# Drawing conclusions from impulse response of a discrete LTI system

Tags: discrete-signals, impulse-response

I have an impulse response of an LTI system which is

```
h(n)= n*u(n)-u(n-2) where n=[0,3] (1)
```

Now regarding the stability and causality of this system, i've drawn the conclusion that the system is causal since the output only relies on past or present values of n and it is stable since n is bounded. In this case n=0,1,2,3. Correct me here if i'm wrong but in case **h(n)** was **u(n) - u(n-2)** without knowing anything about n, it would stil be stable right? And if h(n) is the same as the original (1) but again without knowing anything about **n** it would be unstable correct?

Now i want to analyze this h(n) in odd and even components and also find the linear difference equation of **h(n)** ,but i can't find anything in my textbook that is of any help. It's the first time i've attended a signals and systems course and i'm really struggling to understand a few things, so any help here would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is $h[n]$ given by $n\cdot (u[n]-u[n-2])$ or by $n\cdot u[n] - u[n-2]$?

Comment: @MattL. second one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're right about your conclusions. And now a few hints to help you solve the questions:

1. Your textbook should state somewhere the definition of even and odd parts of a (real-valued) sequence: $$h_e[n]=\frac12\big(h[n]+h[-n]\big)\\h_o[n]=\frac12\big(h[n]-h[-n]\big)$$
2. In this case (FIR filter), the difference equation is simply given by the convolution of the input sequence $x[n]$ with the impulse response $h[n]$: $$y[n]=\sum_kx[k]h[n-k]$$

Comment: 1) Yes you are right. This was so early in the book(like page 9) i don't know how i missed it.Regarding (2) how do i know this is a FIR filter not a IIR one? Is it because i have discrete system, or because it's stable(meaning n is bounded)?

Comment: FIR stands for Finite impulse response. Since h(n) is not infinite it is FIR. It is only between 0 and 3